# How do you import users from Community Server into DNN?

Tags: import, dotnetnuke

A client is switching from Community Server to DNN. We would like to just import all the users including their passwords. It seems like this should work since both products use the .NET SqlMembershipProvider. What tables need to be populated to get a user set up correctly in DNN?

Answer (score 1):

What you will mostlikely need is a membership provider for DNN that allows you to access the CS membership stuff - i have no specific information on this path but that would be my guess and most likely the easiest path

According to Alex Chrome on this post http://dev.communityserver.com/forums/t/488539.aspx

there may be a way to do it with the REST API in CS 2008